# How to bind two methods simultaneously in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have two components - one is **App.js** and other is **Login.js** and i have placed an input field and button in the **Login** and methods are placed in **App.js**. So i want to bind those methods by calling the Login component from the App.js.

Kindly review the logic in **Login>** tags as whenever i click on Flick button , it consoles the value for a second and then page refreshes automatically.

**App.js**

```
handleFlick(e){

    console.log("Oho");
    e.preventdefault()
  }

handleChange(e) {

    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })

render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.name} </h1><br></br>
        <p>first component</p>
        <Login
          handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            handleFlick={this.handleFlick.bind(this)}

        ></Login>
```

**Login.js**

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter name" onChange={(e) => { this.props.handleChange(e) }}></input>
        <button onClick={(e) => { this.props.handleFlick(e) }}>Flick</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: of-course if refreshes because that's what happens when you submit a form. You need to `preventDefault` of form submit not button click. put a onSubmit handler in your form `<form onSubmit={this.props.handleFlick}>` and remove the click handler of your button. Also your button might require `type="submit"`.

Comment: By default buttons have `type="submit"` so clicking on it would submit the form. You could change button `type="button"` to prevent the behaviour. But there are still ways to submit the form (say `Ctrl+Enter`) so you'd better move `handleFlick` to `form.onSubmit` handler.

Comment: Also you probably don't need to create additional function `onChange={(e) => { this.props.handleChange(e) }}` just use `onChange={this.props.handleChange}` to avoid unnecessary renders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<button onClick={(e) => { this.props.handleFlick(e) }}>Flick</button>
```

For this:

```
<button onClick={(e) => { this.props.handleFlick(e); e.preventDefault() }}>Flick</button>
```

type `submit` will by default refresh the page when sended